# How to make all the images of different sizes the same height and width in a page?

Tags: php, html, css

I used

```
<h1> Products </h1>
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <?php
    foreach( $result as $r)
    {
        echo "<div style='
        float: left;
        width:  300px;
        height: 300px;'>";
        echo "<img alt='Missing Picture' src='img/". $r['product_img_name'] . "'>";
        echo "<h2> Name: " . $r['product_name'] . " </h2>";
        echo "<p> Description:   " . $r['product_desc'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p> Price:  " . $r['price'] . "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

but it gives me images that overlap and are too large or small.

Is there anything I can do to make all the different size images the same size and shape and in consistent order?

Comment: You want your images to fit in a container that is 300px by 300px.  What is the aspect ratio of your images? Also, you need to leave space for the `h2` and `p` elements.  Please elaborate and clarify.

Comment: You could always create a <div> with a fixed height and width and set background images. And make the background image size cover.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a bit more complicated than it seems, here is one way of approaching it.

First, define a `div.inner` container to hold the image and specify both a width and height value (100px for example).

Second, define a `div.wrap` container that will hold the `div.inner` block and then the `h2` and `p` elements.  You need to provide some vertical space for the text elements, so for example, give a height of 200px to `div.wrap`.  You can then use `float: left` to create a grid pattern.

To get the images to scale either to the height or width (depending on the native aspect ratio of the image), apply `max-height` and `max-width` of 100% to the image.

Note that unless your images are exactly square (intrinsic height and width are the same), then you will have some extra white space either on the left and right edges of the image (in the case of portrait types images) or on the bottom edge (for landscape images).

```css
div.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

div.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
  <h2>Title Text</h2>
  <p>Some demo text goes here.</p>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
  </div>
  <h2>Title Text</h2>
  <p>Some demo text goes here.</p>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
  </div>
  <h2>Title Text</h2>
  <p>Some demo text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This problem **is** more complicated than it seems!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width and a height on the image tag itself. Best practise is with a css style, but you can do it on the tag itself as well like this...

```
echo "<img style='width:300px;height:300px;' alt='Missing Picture' src='img/". $r['product_img_name'] . "'>";
```

If the original images are not square shaped then forcing the width and height to 300px will cause the images to be stretched which might not look so good.